# Best practice making an AjaxRequest from domain A to domain B in ExtJs4

Tags: ajax, extjs, sencha-touch, cross-domain

So I'm currently implementing a mobile app (Sencha Touch 2.3.1 + PhoneGap 3) that uses JSONP proxies to connect to a Java Jersey REST application so far so good (or kinda...) with that I can load my stores...

But what if let's say I don't want to load anything into a store I just want to call to myBusinessMethodFoo(param1, param2) what are my options in that case?

If it were a web application one option would be to make an Ajax request to my own back-end and then consume a service in another domain and then send data back to my front-end, but since I'm talking about a mobile app that's not an option ...

**So, what is the best practice in this case?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONP technique http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

There is also a JSONP request in Ext (this worked)

```
    Ext.data.JsonP.request({
        url: "http://10.1.50.66:7001/Simulador/webresources/hello",
        callbackKey: 'callback1',
        params: {
        },
        success : function(response) {
            console.log("Spiffing, everything worked");
            // success property
            console.log(response.success);
            // result property
            console.log(response.result);
            console.log(response.msj);
         },
         failure: function(response) {
              console.log(response);
              Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Please try again.', Ext.emptyFn);
          }
    });
```

I'll have to compare thi approach to CORS.

best regards @code4jhon